# How to use an information sent on httpResponse?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am learning about making requests to an api using my backend and when i make this i receive a response with some informations i want to use but i don't know how to use this.

Let me clarify this for you.

**I HAVE THIS CODE TO MAKE THE REQUEST**

```
try
{
    //Set Basic Auth
    var userPagarme = test_key;
    var password = "";
    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userPagarme}:{password}"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64String);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var clienteToAdd = new PagarmeCliente()
    {
        Name = registerUser.Name,
        Code = registerUser.Code,
        Document = registerUser.Document,
        Type = registerUser.Type,
        Document_Type = registerUser.Document_Type,
        Birthdate = registerUser.Birthdate,
        Email = registerUser.Email,
        Gender = registerUser.Gender,
        Address = new PagarmeClienteEndereco()
        {
            city = registerUser.City,
            country = registerUser.Country,
            line_1 = registerUser.Line_1,
            line_2 = registerUser.Line_2,
            state = registerUser.State,
            zip_code = registerUser.Zip_Code
        },
        Phones = new PagarmeClienteTelefone()
        {
            mobile_phone = new PagarmeClienteTelefoneMobile()
            {
                area_code = registerUser.Mobile_phone_area_code,
                country_code = registerUser.Mobile_phone_country_code,
                number = registerUser.Mobile_phone_number
            },
        }
    };

    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clienteToAdd);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlPagarme + "customers", clienteToAdd);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    this.responseBodyJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody); // I have created this prop as an OBJ to receive the obj that was sent. I don't know if it is correct
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    return BadRequest("\nException Caught - Message :{0} " + e.Message);
}
```

That is what i have in this responseBodyJSON and i want to use this property ID to insert on my database but if i make something like this below it doesn't work:

string idThatIWant = responseBodyJSON.id... or something like that.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the many "how can I parse json with c#?" questions.. or take a shortcut, paste your json into https://QuickType.io and follow the instructions on the comments of the code it gives you

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clienteToAdd);

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlPagarme + "customers", clienteToAdd);
```

You converted your model to JSON but you didn't use that jsonString. This could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var respBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagarmeCliente>(responseBody);
```

`respBody.ID` should be available if the class `PagarmeCliente` has the `ID` field you wanted populated.